# Is Newton's law of cooling applicable to an with object constant temp and a changing ambient temperature?

Tags: physics, heat-equation

I am wondering if Newton's law of cooling can be applied in scenario where the object is heating the ambient temperature instead of the other way around.

For example a heater has a temp of x and is heating a room of y when will the room be z? Assume the heater's temperature remains constant.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: This is really a physics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence violates physics.  If the object is heating the surroundings, its temperature will decrease.  It is often useful to regard one object as infinite, which means that taking heat out of it does not change its temperature.  That is always an approximation in the real world, but it can be a useful one.  If the object is massive and the coupling to the surroundings small enough, the approximation may be useful.  Newton's law of cooling assumes that heat loss is through convection and conduction.  Radiation goes as the fourth power of the temperature, so violates the law.  You need to assess whether the approximations made render the result useless.

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Realistically a heater could be electrically or gas powered which would allow it to maintain it's temperature against the heat loss so I believe that in the scenario the assumption would be fair to make.

Comment: That is the sort of assumption that can make the model useful.  Any time you claim some real object has constant temperature/mass/energy etc. it is an approximation.  These approximations can be very useful and accurate, because they show how the rest of the system responds to a constant input, leading to better understanding of the system.  They can also lead to oversights when you are used to an object being massive enough that the property is constant and you get into a case where the approximation breaks down.

Comment: It is easy to say you should always ask yourself if the approximation applies, but there are so many steps in the calculation that if you did that all the time you would never finish.  It is hard.